# Method undefined for the Type Piece problem

Tags: java, abstract-class

I've been working on a project of coding chess in Java. I have an abstract class named `Piece` which has one abstract method and a couple of normal methods. I also have a class for each chess piece, and they all extend `Piece`.

There is a class the represents the board called `Board` as well. In this class, I have a method that checks if the piece at a given position belongs to the other player or not. In this method I call a method from the `Piece` class that gets the color called `getColor()`. when I call this method on a piece it says *"The method getColor() is undefined for the type Piece"* even though it is a method that is created inside the `Piece` class. I really don't know what to do to solve this issue.

Here's the `Piece` class code:

```java
abstract class Piece {
    private Color color;

    /**
     * @param color the color of the piece.
     */
    public Piece(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    /**
     * This method gives a list of all legal moves a piece at a given position in a
     * given board can do.
     * 
     * @param position the position of the piece in the board.
     * @param board    the board in which the piece is in.
     * @return a list of all legal moves.
     */
    abstract List<Position> getPossibleMoves(Position position, Board board);


    /**
     * @return the color of the piece.
     */
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
```

Here's the `Board` class code:

```java
public class Board {
    private Square[][] square;

    /**
     * Initialises an 8 by 8 squares 2d table.
     */
    public Board() {
        this.square = new Square[8][8];
        for (int row = 0; row < square.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < square.length; column++) {
                square[row][column] = new Square<>(null);
            }
        }
    } 

     /**
     * This method sets the given piece in the given position in the board.
     * Throw an exception if the position is not in the board.
     * 
     * @param piece    The piece to be set.
     * @param position The position to set the piece in.
     */
    public <Piece> void setPiece(Piece piece, Position position) {
        if (piece instanceof Piece) {
            if (contains(position)) {
                square[position.getRow()][position.getColumn()].setPiece(piece);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The given position isn't part of the board :" + position);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the piece that is in the given position in the board.
     * Throws an exception if the position is not in the board.
     * 
     * @param pos The position of the piece in the board.
     * @return the piece.
     */
    public <Piece> Piece getPiece(Position pos) {
        Piece piece;
        if (contains(pos)) {
            piece = (Piece) square[pos.getRow()][pos.getColumn()].getPiece();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The given position isn't part of the board :" + pos);
        }
        return piece;
    }
     /**
     * This method determines whether or not the piece at the given position has the
     * same or the opposite color as the given color.
     * throws an exception if position is not in the board.
     * 
     * @param pos the position of the piece to be checked.
     * @param col the color to check if the piece is in the opposite color or not.
     * @return true if the piece is in the opposite color, false otherwise.
     */
    public <Piece> boolean containsOppositeColor(Position pos, Color col) {
        boolean containsOpposite = false;
        if (contains(pos)) {
            if (!isFree(pos)) {
                Piece piece = getPiece(pos);
                containsOpposite = (col.opposite() == piece.getColor());
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The given position isn't part of the board :" + pos);
        }
        return containsOpposite;
    }
```

The problem is at the line that says : `containsOpposite = (col.opposite() == piece.getColor());`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you define a generic type `<Piece>` in a lot of the methods in `Board`. This hides the actual type `Piece` and replaces it with an unknown type basically equivalent to `Object`, which doesn't have a `getColor` method. You need to remove all the occurrences of the generic type `<Piece>` in the methods of `Board`.

So, for example

```java
public <Piece> Piece getPiece(Position pos)
```

should be

```java
public Piece getPiece(Position pos)
```

And the same goes for the other methods:

```java
public <Piece> void setPiece(Piece piece, Position position)
```

should be

```java
public void setPiece(Piece piece, Position position)
```

and

```java
public <Piece> boolean containsOppositeColor(Position pos, Color col)
```

should be

```java
public boolean containsOppositeColor(Position pos, Color col)
```

Comment: I did what you said and removed all ``<Piece>`` definitions from all method signatures and added it in the Board class signature as such: ``public class Board<Piece>``, but the method ``getColor()`` still says : ``The method getColor() is undefined for the type Piece``.

Comment: @LordBaljeet Why did you do that? Why do you think that is necessary? Doing that will also hide the `Piece` class from your code. You shouldn't use generics there for this.

Comment: well when I removed all generic ``<Piece>`` occurrences from my methods signature and replaced them with only the type ``Piece``, for example: ``public Piece getPiece(Position pos)`` it says that ``Piece cannot be resolved to a type``. So i added ``<Piece>`` to the board class signature so it can works.

What I am trying to do is make my board methods work for all subclasses of ``Piece`` such as ``Pawn`` or ``Knight``. I want the methods to take a piece, whichever it is, and treat it.

Comment: @LordBaljeet That means that for some reason the class `Piece` is not visible to your code. Maybe it is in a different package and you didn't import, maybe you're compiling things wrong so that Piece isn't compiled, or something like that. Adding generics is not the answer here.

Comment: Rooteveel My ``Board`` class is in a package called ``model`` and my pieces are all in a subPackage of model that is ``model.pieces``. Piece is an abstract class in the ``model.pieces`` package. I think thats the problem wich makes ``Piece`` type invisible. Any Idea how to solve it? The ``Piece`` class has to stay abstract tho.

Comment: OK, I managed to solve the issue. It was really dumb of me. What I had to do was simply put ``public`` in front of the ``Piece`` class name. Silly me. Anyway, thanks @Mark Rotteveel for your precious help and time.